# How to pass argument between php web and c# WP7

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-7

I am working with my WP7 application and PHP server.
I wonder how to "talk" between PHP and WP7 app??
Could i pass an arguments or list of arguments(which is constructor) from PHP server to WP7 server???
it is as this:
Collapse | Copy Code

Struct User {int id, pass};

If someone know, please teach me.
Thank a lot for helping me.

Comment: So you would like to pass parameters to your php page, then the php page will do some processing and give a response which you'd like to use in your windows-phone-7 code. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Best to create a webservice in PHP and consume it in WP7 application. I had similar issue and invested lots of time but finally solved it using web services :)

Hope this response will help you.